# What is a good mechanism to get production database data into other environments along with de identifying it

Tags: mysql, aws, export, architecture

I am sure this is a solved problem and many people would have a great process already in place.

How do I easily get data in my production server to other environments like staging and testing. We periodically sync data.

I want this process to be easy
I want some de identification done on personally identifiable information e.g swapping name and email with fake data.
I also sometime want to download the data to local. So essentially I want to prevent PII to be exported from database.
Database is mysql RDS, infra is in AWS.

What is a very user friendly and cost effective method to solve this problem

I have considered writing a cli python app which would use mysqldump to download the db and then do de-identification with regex replacements and then uploading to target databases. But this creates a scenario where PII is present in local machines.

I have considered writing a cli python app which would use mysqldump to download the db and then do de-identification with regex replacements and then uploading to target databases. But this creates a scenario where PII is present in local machines